# Send subview 1 layer back

Tags: objective-c, ipad, xcode4.5

I'm doing an iPad application. And I'm newbee in this development.
I have few layer on my view, now i want to send only one layer back.How can i do it.

```
- (void) sendElementToBack:(UIMenuController *)controller {

    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:elementToAlter];
    [[undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] undoSendToBack:elementToAlter];
}

//#pragma mark - Undo/Redo Support for send element to back
- (void) undoSendToBack:(ParentView *)pieceToBringFront {
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:pieceToBringFront];

}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this  !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this may be it helps you,

```
[[self view] exchangeSubviewAtIndex:  withSubviewAtIndex: ];
```

Comment: How do i know the indexes what should be passed ?

Comment: [self.view.subviews indexOfObject: aView];

Comment: @dhcdht what are the integers that we should pass here ? [[self view] exchangeSubviewAtIndex:  withSubviewAtIndex: ];

Comment: The views you want to exchange. You want to send a layer back?This is for views. Layer has a zPosition,you can try.But I don't think it can help you out. You may need create a view for the layer you want send back.

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",self.view.subviews); after getting the values you can assign those values.

Comment: @SunnyI'm getting the frame and layer values. which should i send ?

Comment: simply you have to pass integer values means for ex. in your view there is 3 sub views you want to exchange 3rd view as 1st one and 1st one to 3rd view then give those integer values.